# Using the UINavigationController(Type navigationBarType, Type toolbarType) constructor to specify custom nav bar

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I am attempting to use the `UINavigationController(Type navigationBarType, Type toolbarType)` constructor to specify a custom `UINavigationBar` derived class, defined in C#.

However, all my attempts result in a null ref exception. I presume this is something to do with no native class being found for my managed class?

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(7, 0))
    rootNavController = new UINavigationController(typeof(UnderlayNavigationBar), null);
else
    rootNavController = new UINavigationController();
```

Instead of the 2nd null param, passing in the default `typeof(UIToolbar)` doesn't help either.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ConstructNSObject[NSObject] (IntPtr ptr, System.Type type, MissingCtorResolution missingCtorResolution) [0x00037] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:365
  at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ConstructNSObject (IntPtr ptr, IntPtr klass, MissingCtorResolution missingCtorResolution) [0x00013] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:348
  at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject (IntPtr ptr, MissingCtorResolution missingCtorResolution) [0x00021] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:430
  at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.TryGetOrConstructNSObjectWrapped (IntPtr ptr) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:658
  at at (wrapper native-to-managed) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime:TryGetOrConstructNSObjectWrapped (intptr)
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr (intptr,intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UINavigationController.set_ViewControllers (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController[] value) [0x00028] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UINavigationController.g.cs:345
```

If anyone is interested why I'm using this constructor, I'm porting this guide: http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/custom-uinavigationbar-colors-in-ios7

Comment: Can you show us what you attempted ? (i.e. the code)

Comment: @poupou Yeah that might help, sorry, edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I should have read the call stack in more detail, particularly the `GetNSObject (IntPtr ptr, MissingCtorResolution missingCtorResolution)`.

Makes complete sense now. The instance is constructed in native code, and so needs the managed constructor overload that takes the IntPtr of the native instance. Adding that constructor to my derived class solved it.

```
public UnderlayNavigationBar(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
{
}
```